# rabbitmq log file scraping: are all the logging levels abbreviated to 4 characters?

Tags: logging, rabbitmq, fluentd

- I plan on scraping all the Rabbitmq log files via `fluentd` and so I wanted a rule to make sure all the error messages were captured.
- I noticed immediately that all my log file messages have abbreviations for the logging levels.
- so for example `[info]` and `[warn]` messages

#### rabbitmq log file scraping: are all the logging levels abbreviated to 4 characters? if yes, what is the abbreviation for the error level?

What is the abbreviation for all the others logging level names with longer than 4 characters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Log levels are found here:  https://www.rabbitmq.com/logging.html#log-levels

There are also dbug, noti, erro, and crit

Comment: i checked that page. it does not match up with the log messages i see in the log file. for example: the url you list says "warning" but then the log messages i see have "warn".

Comment: I think it's clear how the full names and abbreviations align.   E.g.,  debug -> dbug, error -> erro, ...  What am I missing?